# Unity 3d SharpPdf C# generation and display

Tags: c#, pdf, unity-game-engine, multiplatform, sharppdf

I was trying to figure out how to generate and display a pdf in a Unity app.
I would like the app, and pdf to be available for iOS, Android and web app. 
Following this tutorial I was able to generate a pdf file and store in the app main folder within the simulator.

http://www.devindia.biz/unity-pdf-generation-with-sharppdf-plugin/

Unfortunately when I try to open the pdf inside the app using

```
Application.OpenURL("FILE://" + path);
```

It does not work.

I also tried iTextSharp with poor outcome and I believe it is not free anymore.

Any suggestion would be more than welcome.

Thanx

**UPDATE**

So I tried to move forward but I'm kind of stuck in the middle: I tried Gallorini's modified SharpPDF program, the generated pdf document, which I called "NewPDF.pdf" is stored in main application folder. Indeed when I run the code in the Editor I'm able to find it in there.
I built a simple gui button and attached a void to it running this c# code to display the document as your suggestion:

```
public void openPdf(){
string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "newPDF.pdf";
Application.OpenURL(path);
Debug.log("Button Clicked");

}
```

when I click the button nothing happens except of course console records Button Clicked.

When I build the program for the web player the pdf is not generated although ApplicationOpenURL works and I am able to display a previously generated pdf by the editor.... I am a bit confused.

When I built the program for Mac Osx nothing happens at all.

On iPhone I get this log from Xcode console:

```
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
Requesting Resolution: 1920x1080
Init: screen size 1920x1080
Initializing Metal device caps
Initialize engine version: 5.1.2f1 (afd2369b692a)

Adding Image Length 0 HEIGTH :8 WIDTH :8
UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
sharpPDF.c__Iterator0:MoveNext()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 65)

UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/newPDF.pdf" is denied.
at Mono.Security.Cryptography.RSAManaged.GenerateKeyPair () [0x00000] in :0
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in :0
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode) [0x00000] in :0
at sharpPDF.pdfDocument.createPDF (System.String outputFile) [0x00000] in :0
at SimplePDF+c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

Adding Image Length 0 HEIGTH :8 WIDTH :8
UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
sharpPDF.c__Iterator0:MoveNext()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 65)

UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/newPDF.pdf" is denied.
at Mono.Security.Cryptography.RSAManaged.GenerateKeyPair () [0x00000] in :0
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in :0
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode) [0x00000] in :0
at sharpPDF.pdfDocument.createPDF (System.String outputFile) [0x00000] in :0
at SimplePDF+c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

Button Clicked
UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SimplePDF:openPdf()
UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall:Invoke(Object[])
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList:Invoke(Object[])
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase:Invoke(Object[])
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
UnityEngine.UI.Button:Press()
UnityEngine.UI.Button:OnPointerClick(PointerEventData)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(IPointerClickHandler, BaseEventData)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1:Invoke(ICancelHandler, BaseEventData)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.TouchInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.TouchInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.TouchInputModule:Process()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 65)
```

I am totally confused. Could you please help me out.

Thanx again.

**UPDATE #2**

I partially solved the problem:

I was able to generate the .pdf file in Unity Editor and in Standalone application on OSX. I realized I had trouble on storing/loading files in Unity.

```
// this is working on Editor. Application.dataPath are reached by the application and files are stored in Assets/StreamingAssets folder under project in Editor     

    #if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_EDITOR_64 
        myDoc.createPDF(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/" + attacName);


        myTable = null;

        #endif

// This is working on Mac standalone application. The file is correctly saved under Application.app/Contents folder

  #if UNITY_STANDALONE

    myDoc.createPDF(Application.dataPath + "/" + attacName);
    myTable = null;
        #endif
```

The code to retrieve and open the file:

```
public void openPdf() {
    string path;

        // tested working on mac

        #if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_EDITOR_64


        path = "file:" +Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/" + attacName;


        #endif

        #if UNITY_STANDALONE

         path = "file:" +Application.dataPath + "/" + attacName;

        #endif

        Application.OpenURL(path);
        Debug.Log ("Button Clicked");

    }
```

So far everything works perfectly.

The pain comes with ios.

I was able to generate a pdf file with the above code in Application.persistentDataPath and getting it back from iTunes (to verify it was created) enabling UIFileSharingEnabled under info.plist. Here's the code:

```
   #if UNITY_IOS 
      myDoc.createPDF(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + attacName);
      myTable = null;
    #endif
```

The trouble is when I try to Application.OpenUrl(path). It seems that c# code is blind to Application.persistentDataPath. Which by the way is /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/"ApplicationName"/Documents/"pdfName".pdf using

```
path = "file://" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + attacName;
    Application.OpenURL(path);
```

I tried also to save the file in StreamingAssets folder but Xcode didn't like it:

UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/F105683E-B2EA-4B0C-81B7-61302C58D56C/PdfReader.app/Data/newPDF.pdf" is denied.
  at Mono.Security.Cryptography.RSAManaged.GenerateKeyPair () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode) [0x00000] in :0 
  at sharpPDF.pdfDocument.createPDF (System.String outputFile) [0x00000] in :0 
  at simplepdf+c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

I then decided to get this wrapper

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/17591

but it can only copy already formatted pdf file from StreamingAssets folder to /Raw folder on iOS device.

I am thinking I have to write my own wrapper to load data from Application.persistentDataPath on iOS, have you got any suggestion to start with?

Thank you again.

Comment: "It does not work" is not really descriptive. How does it not work? Do you see an error? Is the file created? Is it not working when run from inside the editor or on a device? Is the path correct?

Comment: You are right. Ok, the pdf is well rendered and stored in the main folder /UnityApp/*.pdf. When I try to open it from using Application.OpenURL nothing happens: the app do not freeze, no error message, but no pdf visualization. What do I miss? The path is correct and I am running it inside the editor.

Comment: It should be "file:///" + absolute file path. Though I am not sure this will work with a built project, you'd probably have to put this pdf file somewhere on a server

Comment: The link to http://www.devindia.biz/unity-pdf-generation-with-sharppdf-plugin/ is broken